# How to render view with json answer from server

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am using Yii.
I have a php file which represents the view.
It has an input field `<input type='text' id='client' />` which I want to update after I get a response from the server.

The response should be sent after I enter a value in other field and submit it to the server.

Can you refer me to an example on how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just php:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
<input type='text' name="client" id='client' value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['client'] )){ echo $_POST['client']; } ?>" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give an example for calling action in specific controller

Comment: I mean how would it look like for writing the form action attribute

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean @JavaSa. Can you explain a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

Send a `ajax` request on form submit, receive the `json object` from server and assign it to your `textbox`. something like this

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventdefault();
    $.post( "ajax/index", function( data ) {
      $( "#client" ).val( data.client );
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the "ajax/index", I have specific controller and actions

Comment: also please describe what the meaning of  e.preventdefault();

Comment: `e.preventdefault();` will disable the default action of a submit button basically here it will not load the page and send an ajax request, just for an example I put `ajax/index` where `ajax` is your controller and `index` is your action.